# In Tomcat, is it possible for Virtual Host Aliases to direct browsers to a particular context?

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

Say I have a virtual host set up in Tomcat for "mydomain.com" and I want to direct my sub-domains to particular contexts in the virtual host.  For example...

**issues.mydomain.com** would take you to **www.mydomain.com/jira**
**wiki.mydomain.com** would take you to **www.mydomain.com/xwiki**
**vcs.mydomain.com** would take you to **www.mydomain.com/svn**

...and so on.

I'm hoping there's a slick way to do this, perhaps with the <Alias> tag without having to create a virtual host for every sub-domain I want to handle.  Or if there's a completely different solution, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use httpd apache in front of your Tomcat!

That way you could use a named virtual host and direct it to your Tomcat-Application.
It is also more secure since you can forbid any other path within that VHost.

You also don't have to expose your Tomcat to the network at all:
Bind it to localhost and use mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp (the first ist better suited for heavy load) to connect to Tomcat via AJP (normally TCP 8009).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nils, but those answers are outside the bounds of my question.